# How to get the former few rows of current row in structured streaming dataframe

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

I want to get the several rows ahead of current row, however, first, take, rows between are not supported in structured steaming DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use groupByKey and flatMapGroupsWithState can achieve the goal.